# Meaning of "gives sight to the blind"?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer, see-sight-vision-blind

In the morning blessings, we say a bracha that uses the phrase "gives sight to the blind".  What does this phrase mean?  Who are the blind who have been given sight?  Does the phrase refer to us all?  How can this phrase or concept be understood?

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point can be found in [Tehillim 146:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.146.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)

> ה' **פֹּ֘קֵ֤חַ עִוְרִ֗ים** ה' זֹקֵ֣ף כְּפוּפִ֑ים ה' אֹהֵ֥ב צַדִּיקִֽים׃
>
> The LORD **restores sight to the blind**; the LORD makes those who are bent stand straight; the LORD loves the righteous;

Refer to [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.146.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Psalms.146.8.1&lang2=bi) over there who says:

> ה' פוקח עורים. **שהם העורים מחולי העין הוא ירפאם** ואמר זה החולי כי זה העיור כמו האסור לא ימוש ממקומו או פירושו עורים מרוב צרה כי הצרה דומה לחושך והישועה לאור, ובמקרא פסוקים רבים מעידים בזה וכן עשה לישראל **שהיו עורים בגלות** כמו שאמר נגששה כעורים קיר וכאין עינים נגששה כשלנו בצהרים כבנשף

Radak points out that it is a reference to Hashem curing the physical afflictions that cause blindness and not actually blindness, and that is how it is relevant to all of us when we say it in the morning brachos.

He also says that the darkness of exile is comparable to blindness and when the geulah (redemption) comes it will bring a great sense of light and revelation thereby curing us of our "blindness" - which is another way to understand the relevance to all of us saying it even though tG most of us are not blind.

This imagery is indeed suggested in [Yeshaya 59:9-10](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.59.9-10?lang=bi):

> עַל־כֵּ֗ן רָחַ֤ק מִשְׁפָּט֙ מִמֶּ֔נּוּ וְלֹ֥א תַשִּׂיגֵ֖נוּ צְדָקָ֑ה נְקַוֶּ֤ה לָאוֹר֙ וְהִנֵּה־חֹ֔שֶׁךְ לִנְגֹה֖וֹת בָּאֲפֵל֥וֹת נְהַלֵּֽךְ נְגַשְׁשָׁ֤ה כַֽעִוְרִים֙ קִ֔יר וּכְאֵ֥ין עֵינַ֖יִם נְגַשֵּׁ֑שָׁה כָּשַׁ֤לְנוּ בַֽצׇּהֳרַ֙יִם֙ כַּנֶּ֔שֶׁף בָּאַשְׁמַנִּ֖ים כַּמֵּתִֽים
>
> That is why redress is far from us, And vindication does not reach us. We hope for light, and lo! there is darkness; For a gleam, and we must walk in gloom. We grope, like blind men along a wall; Like those without eyes we grope. We stumble at noon, as if in darkness; Among the sturdy, we are like the dead.

Answer (score 2):

The Abudraham on his [commentary to Birchas Hashachar](https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Weekday_Prayers%2C_Morning_Blessings.20?lang=bi) explains that being that the eyes were closed, not really blind, it is still included in the words of this blessing

> כשמעביר ידיו על עיניו מברך פוקח עורים פסוק הוא ואע"פ שאין האדם עור ממש אלא סתום העין נופל בו לשון פקיחה וכן ונפקחו עיניכם אע"פ שלא היו עורים אלא היו סתומים מן הדעת

(This explanation is brought by the Madaane Yom Tov in the Rosh on Brachos 60B)

Comment: This same idea underlies the other blessings there too.